# What are feature not supported by Apache Metamodel Salesforce conenctor

Tags: apache, salesforce, metamodel, apache-metamodel

I had gone through the API provided by Apache metamodel to connect Salesforce.com, most of API are there which can help perform CURD operation. But, i am unable to find the features which are not supported by Apache metamodel API's.
Is there any document reference for complete **API guide** and **feature** document for  Apache metamodel Salesforce.com connector ?

Answer (score 0):

Only direct documentation I can find is on [MetaModel's Wiki](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/METAMODEL/Salesforce.com+support).

To answer this question from a Salesforce side: the most obvious caveat is that Salesforce isn't an ACID or SQL compliant database. The [source](https://github.com/apache/metamodel/tree/e037b0d3f22c25148658548f14ed40edf5479290/salesforce/src/main/java/org/apache/metamodel/salesforce) for the Salesforce connector is the best place to see how everything is translated. The data context is a wrapper around Salesforce's Partner API, so you run the risk of no SQL to API translation being available.